# How to solve issue with mysql workbench results grid?

Tags: mysql, workbench

I'm trying to use mysql workbench as a query editor for my project. My output in the results viewer looks like this:
[image]

Even if I set varbinary/binary characters to show up as non-binary I still get this output. And it is for all fields whether they be text, int, date, etc.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You must choose "Query" - "Execute  (All or Selection) to text" in the up menu